# Attempting to run TensorFlow Federated

Tags: tensorflow, federated

---

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 2>()
1 #100 epoch
----> 2 federated_metrics = evaluator(state.model, val_data)
3 federated_metrics

AttributeError: 'LearningAlgorithmState' object has no attribute 'model'

Attempted different Fed Avg method calls

Comment: Hi @interbyte please give me the code so that i can resolves your issue but i see your error. The error message indicates that the object 'state.model' doesn't have an attribute called 'model'. This suggests that whatever state represents, it doesn't have a model attribute.Make sure that the LearningAlgorithmState object you're passing to evaluator actually has a model attribute. If it doesn't, you'll need to modify your code accordingly.